# Запятая перед словно

Tags: синтаксис

Нужна ли запятая в предложении

Они бились словно дикие звери.

Comment: Спасибо, а в предложении " Они бились друг с другом словно проворные злобные  зверьки, не боясь ничего и никого." нужна ли запятая перед "словно"?  Хотя, думаю, что нужна... Но не совсем разобрался

Comment: При постановке знаков препинания нужно учитывать все факторы: семантику, грамматику, структуру, интонацию. Хотя о семантике говорится не часто, но содержание - это главное, что хочет передать автор, для этого он подбирает подходящую форму. В данном случае предложение придуманное, а с таким текстом сложно и нежелательно работать. Но всё-таки попробуем провести анализ. При использовании распространенного сравнительного оборота с союзом СЛОВНО его обособление является ожидаемым, это обычно попутное сравнение.

Comment: Но это предложение имеет два интонационных варианта. Представим себе, что мы не будем обособлять оборот. Тогда по грамматике это будет однородный ряд из двух обстоятельств (сравнительный оборот и деепричастный оборот). Но по смыслу эти обороты не являются однородными, то есть не раскрывают общую тему, их мало что связывает. Поэтому выбираем интонационный вариант с обособление сравнительного оборота в качестве попутного сравнения. Но повторяю, по семантике этот вариант также не из лучших, но по структуре и грамматике он подходит больше.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Они бИлись, словно дикие звЕри.***

**1) Это обособленный сравнительный оборот.**

При обособлении ударение падает и на сказуемое, и на сравнительный оборот. **Обособлению способствует** структура предложения (две примерно равные по объему фразы),  распространенность оборота, союз СЛОВНО (а не КАК).

2) Оборот со сравнительным союзом **может не обособляться,** если он является **обстоятельством образа действия**  в основном сообщении.

Обычно не обособляется **нераспространенный оборот с союзом КАК**, если он  соответствует  по значению наречию и вписывается в предложение на правах  обстоятельства, например:  ***Они бились как звЕри*** (по-звериному), злобно и беспощадно.

В этом случае ударение падает на оборот (а на сказуемое не падает),  паузы перед оборотом нет.  Таким образом, отсутствие обособления можно проверить на слух.

Comment: Можете привести пример, когда оборот со "словно" не обособляется? А зачем эти "ударения"?

Comment: 1) Заколдован невидимкой,
Дремлет лес под сказку сна.
Словно белою косынкой
Повязалася сосна. 2) В сочетаниях глагол+ обстоятельство ударение падает только на обстоятельство (бились по-звериному, бились как  как звери)

Comment: Вы разве не чувствуете, что это НЕ сравнительный оборот?